# What is the difference between interpose and clojure.string/join?

Tags: clojure

is it fair to say that clojure.string/join is a specialized interpos function for strings? Are there any differences between these functions?

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, they're basically the same. They each take a collection* and a separator, and return a collection where the separator is between each element of the original collection. The major differences between them are:

- `clojure.string/join` calls `toString` on the separator, and each element of the collection, and uses a `StringBuilder` to construct the String.
- `interpose` doesn't effect the separator or collection elements, and returns a lazy list* instead of a fully realized String. It's defined in terms of `interleave`:

  ```
  (drop 1 (interleave (repeat sep) coll))
  ```

Similar concept, but very different implementations.

*I'm ignoring the no-coll version of `interpose` that returns a transducer.

Answer (score 1):

**Interpose**

Interpose takes a separator and sequence, and it returns a **lazy sequence** by adding separator in between the sequence elements

```
user=> (interpose "-" (list "a" "b" "c"))
("a" "-" "b" "-" "c")
user=> (type (interpose "-" (list "a" "b" "c")))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

**Join**

Join takes a separator and sequence, and it returns a  **String**   by joining elements and separator together.

```
user=> (clojure.string/join "-" (list "a" "b" "c"))
"a-b-c"
user=> (type (clojure.string/join "-" (list "a" "b" "c")))
java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right. Note that `interpose` can also return a transducer and is lazy.

Just look at the docstrings or source code:

```
(doc interpose)
(source interpose)
```

etc.